# Flash message not working on Rails 4 after a redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

```
  def show
    email_address = EmailAddress.find_by(confirmation_token: params[:id])
    if email_address.confirm!
      flash[:notice] = "Thanks for confirming your email address (#{email_address.email})"
      flash.keep
      redirect_to user_account_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Invalid confirmation token"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Trying to redirect from this controller to another controller and i want to flash `"Thanks for confirming your email address (#{email_address.email})"` but am not seeing the flash message on the page am redirecting to.

Tried hardcoding a flash message on the other controller and it got displayed.
It's only when I do a redirect the flash message doesn't go through.

Comment: Does `user_account_path` redirect somewhere else as well? If so, `flash.keep` should go there and not in `show`.

Comment: Redirect to somewhere else beside what? I did keep `flash.keep` in both controllers and I still didn't get the message.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you are using `flash.keep`. It is used to keep an existing flash after a second redirect, (i.e. if your action at `user_account_path` ran `redirect_to another_path`). If you aren't doing that, you don't need or want `flash.keep`.

Comment: Sure. I removed the `flash.keep` and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `redirect_to` and flash together:

```
redirect_to user_account_path, notice: "Thanks for confirming your email address (#{email_address.email})"
```

Try to use this way to make redirect and show flash notice.

If this is doesn't work then probably your problem related to rendering flash message. Check content of `flash` helper in view and code which render it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, your suggestion using  `notice` didn't work. I know the rendering isn't a problem because when I hardcode the flash message in the user account controller it renders the message just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing flash code in layout.

Add the following in layouts/application.html.erb in body section:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>
    <% end -%>
```

Comment: `- unless flash.empty?`
   `- flash.each do |name, msg|`
      `- next unless [:alert, :error, :notice].include?(name)`
         `%p.flash_message{id: name}`
            `= msg`
Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that didn't work. That's what I have layouts/application.html.haml